# To get coordinates in the red colored line

Tags: python, opencv

I want to get coordinates in the detected red color lines in the following image.
But when I run the below code, I get all coordinates (red color lines and other identified objects):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'detectedRoof.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst > 0.01*dst.max()] = [255, 0, 0]
cv2.imwrite('outputsimple.jpg', img)

coord = np.where(np.all(img == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1))

lol = zip(coord[0], coord[1])
print(lol)
print ("")

x = np.array(lol, dtype="int")
print (x)

filename1 = open("coordinates_simple.txt", "w")
filename1.write(str(lol))
filename1.close()

plt.scatter(coord[0], coord[1])
plt.show()
```

Input Image

[image: Original image]

Can anyone help me to get only the coordinates of red color lines.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what do mean by "red"? I'm asking since natural red objects (i.e. corners) will always have components in the green and blue channel, too.

Secondly, you detect corners in the gray-scaled image which means corners in all colors. After that you set these objects to blue pixels.

(Thirdly, are you aware that by setting `img[dst > 0.01*dst.max()] = [255, 0, 0]` you set these pixels to blue?)

observing both issues I suggest to modify your respective code similar to this (leave the rest as is):

```
img = cv2.imread(filename, 1)
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
gray = np.float32(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

# detect corners in gray scale image
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

# threshold (red > X, blue and green < Y) such that only reddish corners arec extracted
dst = np.where((dst > 0.01*dst.max()) & (r > 130) & (g < 100) & (b < 100), dst, 0)
```

this way you'll receive all "reddish" corners. You'll just have to play with the threshold.

Note this solution is rather simple (using thresholds)