# getting coordinates of red color in an image(0.01*dst.max()) - python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am working on a problem to get the coordinates of only particular color in an image. So i came across this following code, where i have no idea of the fourth and fifth line . Can someone explain the concept why **0.01 * dst.max()** is used and all. Thanks in advance.

```
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
gray = np.float32(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)
dst = np.where((dst > 0.01 * dst.max()) & (r > 130) & (g < 100) & (b < 100), dst, 0)
img[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 255, 0]
coord = np.where(np.all(img == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1))
coorarray = zip(coord[0], coord[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the code gives the coordinate of the 'corners' in your image.

  ```
  dst > 0.01 * dst.max()
  ```

is a threshold on the 'corner' detection made by 'cornerHarris'. 
Where the 'corner' signal is significative (dst > 0.01 * dst.max()) you create a new blank image and black only the interesting pixels :

```
    img[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 255, 0].
```

Then it determine the coordinates of those black pixels :

```
     coord = np.where(np.all(img == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1))
```

- In your case, if you want to make a particular color detection, you do not need the 'dst' lines, you have to do a selection on the color :

  ```
  colorSelection = (r == 130) & (g == 100) & (b == 100) ### select your color rgb
  img[colorSelection] = [0, 255, 0] ### create a black/white image
  coord = np.where(np.all(img == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1)) ### find the coordinate of your interesting pixels
  ```

Comment: In general threshold used in Image Processing are not universal, they should not work for all possible image. In your case if the images are from the same 'serie', the same selection should work. But you have to try/test/play with the selection to see. 

You can also think to a dynamical selection, the selection can be automatically adapted to the input image in function of 'some parameters' (average, min, max, contrast...)

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your question :s What is 'particular distance coordinates'?

Comment: This is an other question, if you want a clear answer you have to be clearer.  Also I find this question really close to your problem.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787933/to-get-coordinates-in-the-red-colored-line?rq=1